# Emptying an ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am saving records from arrayList and whenever I goes back to the activity where I used that arrayList and save another record, the previous record was also saved together with the new one. How can I empty the arrayList?

```
  ArrayList<String> arraySubBrand = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j=0; j<checkSelected.length; j++)  {
        if(checkSelected[j]==true) {
            String values = BrandListAdapter.mListItems.get(j);
            Cursor rSubBrand = databaseHandler.getReport_SubBrandCode(values);
            if(rSubBrand.moveToFirst()) {
                SubBrandCode = rSubBrand.getString(rSubBrand.getColumnIndex(Constants.SUBBRAND_CODE));
            }
            arraySubBrand.clear();
            arraySubBrand.add(SubBrandCode);

            String subBrand = arraySubBrand.toString();
            subBrand = subBrand.replace("[", "");
            subBrand = subBrand.replace("]", "");

            databaseHandler.SaveSubBrand(new Cons_iReport (ReportCode, subBrand));
        }                       
    }
```

Comment: You do seem to be clearing it.  My question is what `saveSubBrand` is doing.

Comment: It saves the converted arrayList to the database

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused.  You're not providing enough detail to this question to - beyond a shadow of a doubt - isolate the problem.  Provide the output you're getting when you do save it (logs would be useful), and what you're getting when you retrieve the record again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ArrayList.clear()`
It will empty your `ArrayList`.